# Extracting double leading-dash style elements from HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, string

For a desktop Swift project, I'm attempting to extract the `--background-image` property from an HTML page. The snippet code that I'm attempting to extract from is:

```
<div class="artist-header artist-header--fixed " data-test-artist-header="" style="--background-image:url(https://example.com/image.jpeg); --background-color:#f8f8ef;">
```

The end goal is to obtain the `https://example.com/image.jpeg`. It doesn't necessarily matter what the extracted value is. I've been doing most of the tedious parsing on the application-side regardless (ie. `--background-image:url(https://example.com/image.jpeg) ->  https://example.com/image.jpeg`); however, it would be nice to get better at extracting the exact value for the production version of this application.

I gotten fairly close with the following code, but have been unsuccessful for the past 2 hours:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('artist-header')[0].style[0].toString()               // returns "--background-image"
document.getElementsByClassName('artist-header')[0].style.toString()                  // returns "[object CSSStyleDeclaration]"
document.getElementsByClassName('artist-header')[0].style.var(--background-image)     // returns nil
document.getElementsByClassName('artist-header')[0].style.var(--background-image).url // returns nil
```

(Slide to the very right of the code to see the return values of each statement)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [`getPropertyValue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/getPropertyValue). That will give you the entire string:

```
url(https://example.com/image.jpeg)
```

There are many ways you can strip the `url()` from that.

```js
img = document.getElementsByClassName('artist-header')[0].style.getPropertyValue('--background-image');
console.log(img.replace(/url\(([^)]*)\)/, '$1'));
```

```html
<div class="artist-header artist-header--fixed " data-test-artist-header="" style="--background-image:url(https://example.com/image.jpeg); --background-color:#f8f8ef;">
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `getPropertyValue()` to get the variable of background-image.
Then, `slice()` to cut the url.
And `replace()` to remove the backslashes.

```js
var imageUrl = getComputedStyle(document.getElementsByClassName('artist-header')[0]).getPropertyValue('--background-image').slice(4, -1).replace(/\\/g, '');

console.log(imageUrl);
```

```html
<div class="artist-header" style="--background-image:url(https://example.com/image.jpeg)"></div>
```